# How to remove double quotes(") and new lines in between ," and ", in a unix file

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, unix-socket, less-unix

I am getting a comma delimited file with double quotes to string and date fields. we are getting " and new line feeds in string columns like below.

```
"1234","asdf","with"doublequotes","new line
feed","withmultiple""doublequotes"
```

want output like

```
"1234","asdf","withdoublequotes","new linefeed","withmultipledoublequotes"
```

I have tried

```
sed 's/\([^",]\)"\([^",]\)/\1\2/g;s/\([^",]\)""/\1"/g;s/""\([^",]\)/"\1/g' < infile > outfile
```

its removing double quotes in string and removing last double quote like below

```
"1234","asdf","withdoublequotes","new line
feed","withmultiple"doublequotes
```

is there a way to remove " and new line feed comes in between ", and ,"

Answer (score 0):

Your substitutions for two consecutive quotes didn't work because they are placed after the substitution for a sole quote, when only one of the two is left.

We could *remove "* by repeated substitutions (otherwise a quote inserted by the substitution would stay) and *new line feed* by joining the next input line if the current one's end is no quote:

```
sed ':1;/[^"]$/{;N;s/\n//;b1;};:0;s/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1\2/g;t0' <infile >outfile
```